# I can't completely replace Contacts API with People API

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

We have an application that uses the Google Contacts API. Due to the warning

> *"The Google Contacts API is now deprecated and is scheduled for sunset on June 15, 2021. Apps should instead use the People API"*,

we’ve tried to replace Contacts API with People API, but the application doesn’t work the same for the following reason:

With Contacts API, the list of contacts obtained includes both contacts saved by the user and contacts with whom the user have had some interaction without saving them (like sending emails). All these contacts can be modified.

With People API, all contacts are divided into groups, like "Contacts" (saved by the user) and "Other contacts" (not saved), but unlike the Contacts API, only the contacts in the "Contacts" group can be modified.

Will Google make updates to the People API in order to update "Other Contacts" as it was done with the Contacts API? Will there be a version that does this soon?

Comment: There's no way that Stackoverflow users can know what Google plans on doing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not Google support OP should ask google.

Comment: IMO you should adapt your application to the api as is.  You should not wait for google to fix something you think should be fixed